# Inserting images on a webpage in notepad using html5

Tags: image, html

I'm building a webpage in Notepad. I'm using html5 for the first time. I believe I   did the correct coding to insert these images but they don't show up on the page. Here is the code: I could use some help, please. Thank you.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>My practice website</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <html lang="en">
 <meta name="keywords" content="html, css, javascript, history, poems, poetry"/>

 <meta name="description" content="This site is about my personal life, poems, poetry, images of family, myself"/>
 <meta name="author" content="schweidel tyson">

 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainstyesheet.css"/>

 <body style="background-color: #ccffff;">
 </head>

 <body/>
 <h1>Welcome to my website</h1>

 <img src="http://www.html.net/logo.png"/>


 <p>This is basically a personal website build to showcase my fledging talent in webdesign to put up pictures of my family and friends. I also like poetry, so there will be some poems.</p><b/>

 <a href="http://www.html.net/">This is a link to a good html tutorial</a><br/><br/>

 <a href="http://html5doctor.com/">This is another great tutorial link</a><br/><br/>

 <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/">A tutorial for styles link</a>

 <img src=My practice website/My Website/images/high yellow.jpg" width="192 height="256"/><alt="African Amereican light-skined woman"><br/><br/>

 <img src="http://www.zimbio.com/My website/images/trendy.jpg" width="352" width="400"/><alt="African American Woman">

 <img src="My practice website/My website/my new pic.jpg" width="104" height="104"/>  <alt="me at the domiciliary">

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Note that you missed starting `"` for the `src` attribute for one of your `img` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is a bit off:

```
<img src="..." width="104" height="104"/>  <alt="me at the domiciliary">
```

`alt` is just the alternate text for the image. It's an attribute just like `width`, `src` and `height`:

```
<img src="..." width="104" height="104" alt="me at the domiciliary" />
```

Also, make sure your URLs are correct.

---

Also, without a DOCTYPE, your markup is invalid. Include a DOCTYPE (here's a HTML5 one):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  ...
```